# Defining application settings on a project basis in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

In pycharm it is possible to define a custom shell path under application settings:

[image]

In my project I have defined a path to an activate script and an anaconda environment:

```
cmd.exe "/K"  "C:\Users\aboufira\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat"  "C:\Users\aboufira\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\pandas-dev"
```

I would like for this command to be defined *per project*. I have several projects which depend on several environments. I do not wish to have to change it for each project manually.

Is there a way to override the application settings such that the terminal loads the correct environment and associated system variables?

Comment: Doesn't the "*For current project*" icon indicate that the settings on that dialog window are all project-specific?  Have you tried changing this in multiple projects and do they affect each other?

Comment: If conda env or virtual env is used as project interpreter (File - Settings - Project Interpreter), then PyCharm activates it automatically, no need to configure activation